# Why can i run HTML in the browser without creating a HTML file

Tags: html, url, browser

I was suprised when I typed the following into the address bar of the browser

```
data:text,<h1>Whydoesthiswork??</h1>
```

that it actually worked and HTML output was produced

[image]

**I dont understand how can this work , isnt the address bar suppose to convert the sitename into a IP address through the lookup on a DNS. I dont think the job of the address bar is to interpret HTML code.**

*I am confused now*

note: I am using Firefox browser.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 3):

A URI/URL is made of several pieces.  In this context, the `protocol` is the most important, and appears as `protocol:restOfTheUri`. Common examples of protocols are:

- `http`
- `https`
- `data`
- `ftp`
- `file`

These are *all* protocols.

When the browser finds the `data` protocol, it knows what comes next is all that is needed.  There is no need for a network connection or look up.

This is the *point* of the `data:` protocol.

Comment: @user2864740 - That one is tricky. Its not an official protocol.  It works in browsers because the `javascript:` part is actually a *label*.  Most browsers treat the label as a protocol without it being offically designed or registered as one... whereas *real* protocols, like `irc://` or even `telnet://` can trigger running external programs.

Comment: @user2864740 [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) says you are correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:
[data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) (from the Mozilla Developer Network.)

> data URIs, defined by RFC 2397, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents.
>
> The data URIs have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
> ```